# Second Order Damped System (Harmonic Oscillator)

Tags: functions, signal-processing

I'm currently working on an electrical engineering problem involving an ideal operational amplifier. The system itself is governed by the transfer function, which relates output to input:

$$\omega_o^2\over s^2+2\zeta\omega_os+\omega_o$$

A given combination of circuit components yields $\omega_o=10^2$ rad/sec and $\zeta=1/2$. I'm aware that a damping ratio less than one implies oscillations in the impulse response, but am slightly confused about how to answer the next question. The question asks:

"What would you expect at the output, having recorded your own voice as the input, and why? Do you have any suggestions to make the output signal sound more like your recorded voice?"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The last element in the denominator of the transfer function should be $\omega_0^2$, not $\omega_0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Try to figure out the frequency response of the system, i.e. evaluate it (especially its magnitude) for $s=i\omega$. What type of filter is it? Which parameter can be changed to decrease the filter's effect on your voice?